# Get dataset query from sharepoint library from sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-library

I have Datasets and Dataconnections uploaded in a Sharepoint Library. I don't need them to generate SSRS report. What i want to access datasets queries or as a .net dataset object in my code so that i can Export a Custom Excel File.

I am new to sharepoint and don't have enough knowledge. Please help. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Once you get the listitems using SPListItemCollection object, you would be able to assign as a DataTable object. Refer   this link : http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/show/5316/convert-sharepoint-splistcollection-in-datatable-with-decoded   and this link : http://sp77.blogspot.in/2015/04/listitemcollection-as-datatable-in.html

Comment: @SaMolPP thanks for your help. But this is not required. StoreDirectoryDataSetFIM and StoreDirectoryDataSetGCHRIS are two DataSets of .rsd type file with their corresponding DataSources. All i want to get a single DataSet from list and get its query or object of dataset. Please help!!